# Folder path issue to replace image on server

Tags: javascript, php, windows-server-2008

At run time I am trying to replace an image in my server folder `http://kceesay.pointclick.net/finger_reader/client-side/images/`. but it's not working.

I think there is a path issue.

Here is my code :-

```
GrFingerX.CapSaveRawImageToFile(rawImg, w, h, "http://kceesay.pointclick.net/finger_reader/client-side/images/teste.bmp", 501);
```

I have also tried this with absolute and relative path but not working.

Comment: dose the image have the correct perms?

Comment: yes image have correct perms.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Ok, so let me brief it for you. What I am trying to do is ,saving an image on Windows Server using Javascript .Here is the code:- "GrFingerX.CapSaveRawImageToFile(rawImg, w, h, "http://kceesay.pointclick.net/finger_reader/client-side/images/teste.bmp", 501);" but it's not saving that image on Windows Server.